# Change the css of all the elements based on an IF condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Im trying to hide some li elements on this website with the help of a chrome extensions "Custom Javascript"

I've tested my code on a local file and it only works with the first li:

```
var b = document.querySelector("span.price_value").innerHTML;
var processed = b.replace(/ /g, '');
var output = parseInt(processed, 10);
if (output >= 5000) {
    document.querySelector(".item").style.display = "none";
}
```

How can i change the css property of all the li elements that matches that condition?

querySelectorAll just returns an undefined error.

Comment: `document.querySelector` always gives you first matching element. Try `document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), You can use [`.filter(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) to get all `span.price_value` element passing test condition, then using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target ancestor element to `.hide()`

```
//Get all span having text > 500
$("span.price_value").filter(function () {
    var processed = $(this).html().replace(/ /g, '');
    var output = parseInt(processed, 10);
    return output >= 5000
})
.closest(".item") //Target parent items
.hide() //Hide
```

Comment: Thank god for Jquery!


The for loop with vanillaJS Did work too , but this one is the right one for me :D

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use querySelectorAll which returns a node list, instead of querySelector, which returns the first node it finds.

You'll need to use some kind of 'for' loop to affect each node in the list.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()` returns the first element that matches the selector. You can use `querySelectorAll()` to retrieve a list of elements that you can then iterate over.

```
for (var item of document.querySelectorAll("span.price_value")) {
    var processed = item.innerHTML.replace(/ /g, '');
    var output = parseInt(processed, 10);
    if (output >= 5000) {
        item.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

querySelectorAll returns a list of items. Iterate through that and set each element to display none.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.style.display = "none"
});
```